# Sorting results with sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm using Sphinx 2.0.5.

sphinx.config:

```
index test
{
    type      = mysql
    sql_host  = host
    sql_user  = user
    sql_pass  = pass
    sql_db    = db

    sql_query = SELECT id, string \
                FROM table
}
```

sphinx.php:

```
$sphinx = new SphinxClient();

$sphinx->SetServer('localhost', 3312);
$sphinx->SetConnectTimeout(1);

$sphinx->SetLimits(0, 15);

$sphinx->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL);
$ret = $sphinx->query($query, 'index');
```

In "string"  there are lines like

```
"mouse, screen, keyboard, green house"
"green house, computer, keyboard, green house"
```

I'd like to sort by :
1- the number of different keywords found in the line
2- the total number of keywords found in the line

For example, if I search for "green house", I'd like to get "green house, computer, keyboard, green house" in first. But if I search for "green house screen", "mouse, screen, keyboard, green house" should be in first.

Do you have an idea of what kind of sorting I should use ?

Thanks.

Comment: With SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED and SPH_RANK_WORDCOUNT I can sort by the total number of keywords found. How can I have the lines with all the keywords in first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would put , into phrase_boundary
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-phrase-boundary

which seperates phrases into seperate boundaries. Can now use primoxy to affect results.

Then would write the search something like

```
$cl->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$cl->setRankingMode(SPH_RANK_WORDCOUNT);
$cl->Query('"green house"~10 | "green house" | (green house)',$index);
```

Can choose exactly what factors you like, to affect the results. Gets more complicated with 3(or more!) word queries, as have to expand all the combinations into the query.

(I'm not sure if this results in your exact specifications - to be honest they arent clear - but this is a general solution for this type of situation - matching tag lists)

Comment: because it scratched an itch to write some PHP, here is a function to do it, no matter how long the search query :) http://pastebin.com/8RGY8MGe - only works though if the input is a simple list of space seperated keywords. If contains any special syntax, will break.

Comment: The results are far better, thanks ! Now I just need to make it work with multiple keywords and spaces queries ("green house, computer" for example)...